# Cannot implicity convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<B> to System.Collections.Generic.List<B>

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

With the code below i get this error and need help with how to let method Load return `List<B>`

Cannot implicity convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to System.Collections.Generic.List

```
public class A
    {
      public List<B> Load(Collection coll)
      {
        List<B> list = from x in coll select new B {Prop1 = x.title, Prop2 = x.dept};
        return list;
      }
    }

public class B
{
  public string Prop1 {get;set;}
  public string Prop2 {get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a List? Remember that this materializes the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query returns an `IEnumerable`, while your method must return a `List<B>`.
You can convert the result of your query to a list via the `ToList()` extension method.

```
public class A
{
   public List<B> Load(Collection coll)
   {
       List<B> list = (from x in coll select new B {Prop1 = x.title, Prop2 = x.dept}).ToList();
       return list;
   }
}
```

The type of the list should be inferred automatically by the compiler. Were it not, you would need to call `ToList<B>()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the enumeration to a list, there's an extension method to do that for you e.g. try this:

```
    var result = from x in coll select new B {Prop1 = x.title, Prop2 = x.dept};
    return result.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert an object of a more generic type to a more specific.

Let's imagine, that we have a List of B and IEnumerable of B:

```
List<B> BList = ...
IEnumerable<B> BQuery = ...
```

You can do this:

```
IEnumerable<B> collection = BList;
```

But you can't do this:

```
List<B> collection = BQuery;
```

because collection is a more specific object, than IEnumerable.

So, you should use an extension method ToList() in your case:

```
(from x in coll
select new B 
  {
    Prop1 = x.title, 
    Prop2 = x.dept
  }
).ToList()
```