# ienumerable<string> to list<string>

Tags: c#, list, compiler-errors, compare

I have the following code snippet

```
        string[] lines = objects.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);  
        //convert the array into a list for easier comparison
        List<string> StringtoList = lines.OfType<string>().ToList();

        //get the database list here
        List<string> sensitiveApps = testConnection.SelectSensitive();

        //compare the 2 lists to get the difference
        List<string> except = sensitiveApps.Except(StringtoList,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

However, I keep getting the above error, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicity convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<B> to System.Collections.Generic.List<B>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668648/cannot-implicity-convert-type-system-collections-generic-ienumerableb-to-syste)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the last line is throwing an exception. Try changing:

```
List<string> except = sensitiveApps.Except(StringtoList,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

to:

```
List<string> except = sensitiveApps.Except(StringtoList,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

This exception is occurring as `Except` will be returning an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I'd actually go the other way around (change the type of except to IEnumerable, or even better just to 'var' and forget about it), that would promote loose coupling

Comment: I guess it all depends on whether he actually needs a list or an enumerable. Not enough code to judge either way.

Comment: Thanks it works now! I'm relatively new to C#, having coded in Java for the pass 3 years in school.. Got lot's to learn, but thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

While Daniel's suggestion is certainly correct, I'd like to propose an alternative: use `HashSet<string>` which is better designed for set-based operations like Except.

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(sensitiveApps, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
set.ExceptWith(lines);
```

There is no need to do the `lines.OfType<string>().ToList()` as lines is `IEnumerable<string>`. Then, if you do need the resulting set as a list, simply call `set.ToList()`.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** This assumes that the order of sensitiveApps does not matter.